# PHP7 preg_replace_callback() broke multiple Arrays loop

Tags: php, html, regex

Hi guys I need help in fixing this mess created by PHP7

Originally I used this bit of code to replace values ^0 to ^9 with HTML colour codes for output later and it worked beautifully.

My original post i needed help with form about 2 years back... 
[PHP Preg_replace and Call of Duty Colour Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996923/php-preg-replace-and-call-of-duty-colour-issue)

```
$Find        = array('/\^(\d)([^\^]*)/e');
$Colors  = array("#000000","#FF0000","#00F100","#FFCC00","#0F04E8","#04E8E7","#F75AF6","#FFFFFF","#7E7E7E","#6E3C3C");
$Replace     = array('"<font color=\"".$Colors["$1"]."\">$2</font>"');
$DataOut     = preg_replace($Find, $Replace, $QueryString);
```

However now with PHP7 using preg_replace_callback()
my output doesn't replace anything anymore.

I have tried a couple of different approaches and read the documentation on 
preg_replace_callback() but Im unable to get this working again.

Not very happy with PHP7, it seems to break more things and cause more issues then what its worth and Im lost atm :( HELP Please

Comment: try something like [`$DataOut = preg_replace_callback($Find, function($m) use (&$Colors) {
  return '<font color="'.$Colors[$m[1]].'">'.$m[2].'</font>';
}, $QueryString);`](https://eval.in/726048)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately its a no go. When I try that... it doesn't give any output and the php error log says PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead

Comment: @Banshee10000: Remove the `e` flag.

Comment: Ah I got it.  = array('/\^(\d)([^\^]*)/'); did the trick, Thanks Guys